# Pass Password-Manager for Aerc eMail-client

Tags: email, password, password-store

I use *Aerc eMail-client* on Archlinux.

I have an **gmail**-account, which I was setting up like this: https://oren.github.io/articles/text-based-gmail/. So I integrated the special password-App.

How can I integrate pass password-manager in my aerc eMail client? So that I don't have to insert plaintext password in my `~/.config/aerc`?

The wiki is too cryptic for my level: [https://man.sr.ht/~rjarry/aerc/integrations/password-manager.md#get-password-from-your-password-manager](https://man.sr.ht/%7Erjarry/aerc/integrations/password-manager.md#get-password-from-your-password-manager)

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: I don’t know anything about `aerc` or `secret-tool`…**

I use a *somewhat* similar setup with the `mutt` e-mail client and the `pass` (a.k.a. password-store) password manager.

**As I understand it**, you should be able to configure `aerc` to query password-store with a configuration like:

```
source-cred-cmd = /usr/bin/pass show jonhdoe@gmail.com
```

Note that you may have to adapt the path to the `pass` executable and replace `jonhdoe@gmail.com` with the name of the password store that contains you gmail password.

Comment: Thanks. I anyway changed to mutt e-mail. Now I am happy.